# How to save on the next row from one existing data of copied google spreadsheet to another google spreadsheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this dilemma where i recorded a macro to copy a row to another sheet but so happens every time i run the macro it will always save on the same row. what can I add to this script in order for the macro to save it after the previously saved data?

Current Code:

```
    function SAVING2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:O2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit RAW'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'audit dump\'!A2:O2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

What I wish to accomplish:

For the macro to save the next set of data after the previous

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your script, from `spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit RAW'), true);` and `spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();`, the destination range is always "A2" of "Audit RAW" sheet. I think that this is the reason of your issue. In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function SAVING2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var src = spreadsheet.getRange('\'audit dump\'!A2:O2');
  var dstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Audit RAW");
  var dst = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  src.copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

- In this modification, the destination range is set as the next row of the last row. By this, the copied value is appended to the destination sheet.

#### Reference:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)